# How to get F from this transcendental complex equation?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I want to solve this transcendental equation, but I don't know the step by step to get `F` in form equation and value of `F`

```
f[F] = [exp^(I*p*b)/(16*A^2*B*H) {((A + H)^2)[(A + B)^2*exp^(2*I (k (a - b) - q*a)) - (A - B)^2*exp^(-2*I (k (a - b) - q*a))] + ((A - H)^2)[(A - B)^2*exp^(-2*I (k (a - b) + q*a)) - (A + B)^2*exp^(2*I (k (a - b) + q*a))] + 2 (A^2 - B^2) (A^2 - H^2)[exp^(2*I*q*a) - exp^(-2*I*q*a)]}] = 0
```

I need solution `F` in form equation (F=...)
and, where

```
n = 2;
h = 1;
a = 0.01;
b = 0.02;
m = 1;
h = 1;
c = 137.036;
S1 = 0;
S2 = 0;
V1 = 0;
V2 = 50.000;
k = Sqrt[F^2 - m^2*c^4]/(h*c);
p = Sqrt[(F + m*c^2 - V2 + S2) (F - m*c^2 - V2 - S2)]/(h*c);
q = Sqrt[(F + m*c^2 - V1 + S1) (F - m*c^2 - V1 - S1)]/(h*c);
A = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2)/(F + m*c^2)];
B = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2 - V2 - S2)/(F + m*c^2 - V2 + S2)];
H = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2 - V1 - S1)/(F + m*c^2 - V1 + S1)];
```

I want to get value of F by using the variables that have been known above

Help me to get F function and value of F, please.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Put this into Mathematica and evaluate it and look at the resulting graph

```
n = 2; h = 1; a = 1/100; b = 2/100; m = 1; h = 1;
c = 137036/1000; S1 = 0; S2 = 0; V1 = 0; V2 = 50;
k = Sqrt[F^2 - m^2*c^4]/(h*c);
p = Sqrt[(F + m*c^2 - V2 + S2) (F - m*c^2 - V2 - S2)]/(h*c);
q = Sqrt[(F + m*c^2 - V1 + S1) (F - m*c^2 - V1 - S1)]/(h*c);
A = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2)/(F + m*c^2)];
B = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2 - V2 - S2)/(F + m*c^2 - V2 + S2)];
H = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2 - V1 - S1)/(F + m*c^2 - V1 + S1)];
f[F_]:=(E^(I*p*b)/(16*A^2*B*H)(((A+H)^2)((A+B)^2*E^(2*I(k(a-b)-q*a))-
  (A-B)^2*E^(-2*I(k(a-b)-q*a)))+((A-H)^2)((A-B)^2*E^(-2*I(k(a-b)+q*a))-
  (A+B)^2*E^(2*I(k(a-b)+q*a)))+2(A^2-B^2)(A^2-H^2)(E^(2*I*q*a)-E^(-2*I*q*a))));
Plot[{Re[f[F]],Im[f[F]]},{F,-100000,100000},AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotPoints->1000,PlotRange->All]
```

That will plot the real part and the imaginary part of your expression. It does not appear that there is an F such that your function clearly equals zero.

Does this make your problem clear?

Comment: On a different scale the plot shows a root in the vicinity of F = 18827, or have I missed something.

Comment: I have put it into Mathematica, but it does not shown any plot after I run it. What should I do?  @Bill

Comment: How can you (@LouisB) get F=18827 ? Do you immediately copy and paste the answer shown by Bill on your Mathematica or add something before running the formula ?

Comment: I restart Mathematica so it forgets any previous assignments and cached values, scrape my code above off the screen, paste it into the Mathematica notebook, tap <shift><enter> and a couple of seconds later I see the plot. Then I change the plot to be `Plot[{Re[f[F]],Im[f[F]]},{F,18826,18828}]` and see another plot.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much @Bill

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that works fairly well.  First, define the parameters with lots of precision, say 100 decimal places here

```
{h = 1, a = 0.01`100, b = 0.02`100, m = 1, c = 137.036`100,
  S1 = 0, S2 = 0, V1 = 0, V2 = 50};
```

Now define the functions of variable $F$ and the overall function, $f$, whose root(s) we want to find.

```
k = Sqrt[F^2 - m^2*c^4]/(h*c);
p = Sqrt[(F + m*c^2 - V2 + S2) (F - m*c^2 - V2 - S2)]/(h*c);
q = Sqrt[(F + m*c^2 - V1 + S1) (F - m*c^2 - V1 - S1)]/(h*c);
A = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2)/(F + m*c^2)];
B = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2 - V2 - S2)/(F + m*c^2 - V2 + S2)];
H = Sqrt[(F - m*c^2 - V1 - S1)/(F + m*c^2 - V1 + S1)];

f = (E^(I*p*b)/(16*A^2*B*H) (((A + H)^2) ((A + B)^2*
          E^(2*I (k (a - b) - q*a)) - (A - B)^2*
          E^(-2*I (k (a - b) - q*a))) + ((A - H)^2) ((A - B)^2*
          E^(-2*I (k (a - b) + q*a)) - (A + B)^2*
          E^(2*I (k (a - b) + q*a))) + 
      2 (A^2 - B^2) (A^2 - H^2) (E^(2*I*q*a) - E^(-2*I*q*a))));
```

Now make a plot and look for a root.  Since there are complex numbers in the formula, use `ReImPlot`.

```
ReImPlot[f, {F, 18000, 20000}]
```

[image]

The plot shows what may be root around F=18800.  In this case `FindInstance` is able to locate the root.

```
soln = FindInstance[{f == 0, 18700 < F < 18900}, F] //
       Flatten // First;
N[{F, f} /. soln, 10]

(*  {18826.96586, 0.*10^-96 + 0.*10^-96 I}  *)
```

It doesn't hurt to zoom in on the root,

```
ReImPlot[f, {F, 18825, 18830}]
```

[image]

Note that this root is not a root of the trig form ($\tan(qa) = ... $) shown in the OP.  It may be interesting to see what happens without the 100 decimal places of precision.  It may also be interesting to try to get root using `Solve` or `NSolve` or `FindRoot` or by minimizing `Abs[f]` or `f*Conjugate[f]`.  It may be interesting to use `FunctionDomain` on the `{p, k, q, A, B, H}` and `f` functions.

Comment: Thankyou very much @LouisB. By the way, if the value of the variables n, h, b, m, c, S1, S2, V1, and V2 are not known, can the equation F be determined?

Comment: @Afaf_H  If such solutions do exist the key to finding them probably lies in the expressions (boundary conditions?) and the model that led to your expressions for $f, k, p, q,$ etc.  If I come up with anything, I'll post a new answer to this question.  Also, you may want to use `Manipulate` to  study how the various parameters affect the root(s).  Plotting the $k, p, q, A, B, H$ functions may also provide insight into where to look for roots.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much @LouisB. Oh yeah, sorry in advance, would you please if I asked you more about this discussion via email for example or other social media, not in a public forum?